# submit form in new window and reload current window with new url

Tags: jquery, forms, new-window

I am trying to submit a form in new window and after submit, I am reloading the current window with new url. Below is my code.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/submit/" method="get" name="myform" id="myform" target="_blank">
    <div>
        <div>Your Name:</div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="image" src="http://www.example.com/submit_image.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(){
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working fine in Firefox and IE, but not in Google Chrome. The issue in chrome is, it submits the form in new window but it does not reload the current window with new url.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this? My idea is, to submit this form in new window and reload the current window with different url.

Comment: Do u have anyy errors..? Have you checked the browser console.??

Comment: Yes, I checked that but there was no error in console.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code, may be helpful to you,

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

replace with this code

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "google.com";},500);
```

Comment: This will open new window. But I want the www.xyz.com in current window.

Comment: Please use this code setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "http://www.google.com"},500);

Comment: thank you. Please conferm my answer.. for getting reputation.

Answer (score 0):

May be this you want to add

```
target='_blank'
```

And that should look like this

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/submit/" method="get" name="myform" id="myform" target="_blank" >
 <div>
    <div>Your Name:</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="image" src="http://www.example.com/submit_image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

To reload current page, use `location.reload();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(){
         location.reload();  // window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I have added that and because of that attribute form is submitting in new window. Also the code in jquery submit event is working fine. It reloads the current window. But it does not work in Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it submits the data in new window, but does not reload the current page.

Comment: No, still not working. It opens new window and make focus on new window. No effect on main window.